# Add custom template in CKEditor 3 using classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, ckeditor

I have a website that uses classic ASP to render settings for CKEditor 3.

On the serverside I have:

```
 <%
 Dim Editor

 Set Editor = New CKEditor
 Editor.basePath = "/ckeditor/"
 Editor.Config("contentsCss") = "/Styles/Editor.css"
 Editor.Config("templates_files") = "/templates/news.js"
 Editor.Config("width") = 570;
 Editor.editor "Html", Html
 Set Editor = Nothing
 %>
```

And in news.js I have:

```
CKEDITOR.addTemplates('news',
{
   imagesPath: CKEDITOR.getUrl('/JavaScripts/ckeditor_3.6.3/templates/images/'),
   templates:
    [
        {
        title: 'News Template',
        //image: 'template1.gif',
        html:
            '<h3>Template 2</h3>' +
            '<p>Type your text here.</p>'
    }
    ]
});
```

And it renders:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js?t=C3HA5RM"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
    CKEDITOR.replace('Html', {"contentsCss": "\u002FStyles\u002FEditor.css","templates_files": "\u002Ftemplates\u002Fnews.js","width": 570}); 
//]]></script>
```

It seems like it takes the path provided (/templates)... and does a 404 with each letter from it.... i.e /t /e /m ...

What might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.templates_files), the templates_files should be an array of strings, even if you use only one file, so the correct configuration is

```
Editor.Config("templates_files") = Array("/templates/news.js")
```